# Changing Desktop environment

Tags: gnome

Can anyone tell me the most proper commands with all steps to change my desktop environment to GNOME 3?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Just one more question if i install gnome shell with this method will my unity enviroment remain the same